# Calling a procedure from its non native form

Tags: vb.net, function

Ok, so

1. frmResult populates a ListView with various calculations
2. frmMenu has an export button (see code below). Pressing this is supposed to export the data in the ListView to a txt file. Currently, this button does not work. It says, List View is undeclared - obviously because the code shown below is not 'seeing' data held in frmResult

Question – how do I call the procedures stored in frmResult so that frmMenu can 'see' it.

```
Public Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
    Dim fileSaved As Boolean
    Dim filePath As String
    Do Until fileSaved
        'Request filename from user
        Dim saveFile As String = InputBox("Enter a file name to save this message")
        'Click Cancel to exit saving the work
        If saveFile = "" Then Exit Sub
        '
        Dim docs As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        filePath = IO.Path.Combine(docs, "Visual Studio 2013\Projects", saveFile & ".txt")

        fileSaved = True
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filePath) Then
            Dim msg As String = "File Already Exists. Do You Wish To Overwrite it?"
            Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or MsgBoxStyle.Critical
            fileSaved = (MsgBox(msg, style, "Warning") = MsgBoxResult.Yes)
        End If
    Loop

    'the filePath String contains the path you want to save the file to.
    Dim rtb As New RichTextBox
    rtb.AppendText("Generation, Num Of Juveniles, Num of Adults, Num of Semiles, Total" & vbNewLine)
    For Each saveitem As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        rtb.AppendText(
                       saveitem.Text & ", " &
                       saveitem.SubItems(1).Text & ", " &
                       saveitem.SubItems(2).Text & ", " &
                       saveitem.SubItems(3).Text & ", " &
                       saveitem.SubItems(4).Text & vbNewLine)
    Next
    rtb.SaveFile(filePath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
Public Sub Init()
    '... (all the code)
End Sub

Private Sub Results_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call Init()
End Sub
```

You can call `Init()` from every form load you want. Maybe you want to create a module and store there your methods.

By the way, you only use `Function` when your methods needs to return a value.

If your code uses elements of the form (or other objects not constant) you need to pass those to the method, like this:

```
Public Sub Init(myListView As ListView) 
    myListView.Items.Add("something")
    '...
End Sub

Private Sub Results_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call Init(ListView1)
End Sub
```

You can add as many parameters as you need. You have to learn the basics before going ant further.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I did wonder as all examples of a function I have read about return a value. I will test out the idea and see if it works now.

Comment: Ah, I have hit a problem, if a follow your suggestion of putting all the code in my module with Public Sub Init(), I then get a problem with ListViewItem1 not being declared (since the ListView is in frmSetGeneration Values.  This was my problem before I came across the idea of modules

Comment: Then the method has to take the needed objects as parameters. I edit the answer

Comment: From the OP's code, it appears that `Init` will include code that references controls on the form from which `Init` is called. That suggests that the `Init` method will need an argument that references the calling form (or perhaps just the ListView on the calling form).

Comment: @Blackwood is already added. Maybe the best idea will be to create an Interface to represent the type of form he wants, but seems to complicated right now for him.

Comment: OK. Let me go back and do some more research. Is it possible to temporary put a post on hold to stop others wasting time. I'm conscious that this site is viewed by real professionals

Comment: @Student The best way to let people know that you are not wanting additional answers would be to mark this post as the answer. If you have a followup question, you could post a new question, or if it's a minor point, you could comment here. SysDragon will be automatically notified that you posted a comment.

Comment: @Blackwood. Thank you. Have reworked the question to help focus my own research and marked the response as correct so as to prevent further dialogue

Comment: @SysDragon I have rephrased my question as it showed some serious flaws which you have kindly pointed out. I will do some more research based on your suggestions.Thank you

Comment: @SysDragon I am still struggling here but have made substantial changes to the original code I posted.  Please can you help me to understand how to implement your solution, I am struggling to pass the parameters

Comment: @Student What are your doubts? What you don't understand?

Comment: @SysDragon I have corrected my code along the lines you suggest (see post) but both LIstView1 and Init causes an error in frm Results. They are not decalred?? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @SysDragon Thanks for your help. I burned the midnight oil and came up with a solution that solved my particular problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a great piece of [literature](http://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/rzenner/chapter_7.htm) for those struggling with the basics like myself. 
You can write code to access objects on a different form.  However, you must fully identify the name of the object by preceding it with the object variable name.

```
Dim resultsForm As New frmResults
resultsForm.lblAverage.Text = sngAverage.ToString()
```

In these statements, for example, I have declared an object variable called resultsForm that is linked to the form frmResults.  The second statement assigns the string value of sngAverage to the lblAverage label box on the frmResults form.

In my code, I needed to change the line that said:

```
For Each saveitem As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
```

To this:

```
For Each saveitem As ListViewItem In Results.ListView1.Items
```

I also needed to make sure that the procedure on formResults was made Public not Private

Comment: be careful do not instantiate multiple times the form

Comment: Rather than one form getting all up in another form business - that is, having to know the control names/type on *other* forms - it is usually better to "push" the data from one form to another using a method (e.g. `Public Sub NewListViewData(...)` then let the form which owns the control take care of things.  Of course, if/when the app is not centered around forms, but Classes, it is even easier.